# Java Lombok "@Getter" is not applicable to field

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I've been trying to get Lombok working in IntelliJ IDEA but whenever I try to use any of its annotations, I get an error message that goes like this:

```
Error:(5, 5) java: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration
```

My code looks like this, using their example on their homepage.

```
import jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.annotations.Getter;

public class GetterSetterExample {
    @Getter
    private int age = 10;
}
```

I have installed the lombok plugin, and enabled the annotation processor in settings. I'm using IntelliJ 15 with java 1.8.0_40.

I can't find anyone with the same problem as me which is why I am asking here if anyone knows what's going on.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use

```java
import lombok.Getter;
```

instead of:

```java
import jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.annotations.Getter;
```

Answer (score 2):

For Lombok to work properly, you have to install two things:

1. lombok *dependency* (or single `*.jar` file for hardcod)

   ```xml
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
     <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
     <version>1.18.10</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. *plugin* to your IDE so that it can see those implicit getters/setters.